# How to prevent a logged in user to come back to the login/signup screens in Android?

Tags: android

In my app user first sees a screen with a logo and login/register buttons.
There are log in and register screens and after them, the user goes to the home screen.

I want to prevent them from seeing the first screen and/or the login/signup screens after they've logged in/registered, until they sign out.

This is what I've tried:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private boolean isUserLoggedIn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        isUserLoggedIn = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("userLoggedInState", false);
        if(isUserLoggedIn) {
            finish();
        }
`}
```

and I expected it to redirect them back to calling activity, but instead it doesnt do that.
And even worse, If I've already logged in and I go to some other app, when I come back to this one, Im getting thrown out, because in shared preferences Im already logged in, so this finish() takes me back to the previous app. And this is my launher activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    isUserLoggedIn = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("userLoggedInState", false);
    if(isUserLoggedIn) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , NameOfActivityToStart.class);
        intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

with this code this page and any older pages delete from history and if user clicked on back button not seen this page.

Comment: do i put this in MainActivity? What do I put there instead of "yourcontext" and "youractivity"?

Comment: You can use "this" in place of yourcontext and NameOfActivityToStart.class in place youractivity.

Comment: put this where you want check that is log on or not, and your context is MainActivity.this and your activity is next class that you want to call "classname.class"

Answer (score 2):

You can start another activity just before calling finish() method.

When you want to get result from an Activity, you will start that activity using startActivityForResult method. And then you can override the onBackPressed method of the activity from which you can expecting some result.

```
public void onBackPressed() { 
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    // add any value to intent
    setResult(RESULT_CANCALLED, intent); 
    super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```

You will receive this intent in

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    // in this method
}
```

of calling activity.

Comment: but how do I know which is the previous activity? And what if previous activity is not from this app?

Comment: You can pass different values through Intent to identify calling activity and retrieve it using getIntent() method in this activity.

Comment: when user hits the "back" button I dont think (Im not sure) this fires up an intent, so I cant get an intent, or can I? Can you provide an example?

Comment: When you want to get result from an Activity, you will start that activity using startActivityForResult method. And then you can override the onBackPressed method of the activity from which you can expecting some result. public void onBackPressed() { Intent intent = new Intent(); setResult(RESULT_CANCALLED, intent); super.onBackPressed(); }

Comment: what do I put in onActivityResult in MainActivity?

Comment: and why do I need an intent in onBackPressed? I dont intent to send the user anywhere, I dont want them to see the MainActivity page